# How to add reject message to Discord py role restricted commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, roles, discord.py

I have this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from itertools import cycle
from discord.utils import get
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')


TOKEN = ''


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')



@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(":smiley: :wave: Hello, there! :heart: ")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

How I can set a reject message?
I mean if someone use that command but he doesn't have Admin role, bot will say something like
"You aren't admin buddy!"

I've tried this but did not work

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(":smiley: :wave: Hello, there! :heart: ")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't use this!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user calls the test command and they do not have the 'Admin' role, a commands.MissingRole error is thrown. You can catch this with [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from itertools import cycle
from discord.utils import get
import os

TOKEN = ''

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(":smiley: :wave: Hello, there! :heart: ")

@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send('''You aren't admin buddy!''')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: If this person were to have multiple permission commands, this will not work.

Comment: @FluxedScript, If you want to specify multiple permission commands `@commands.has_any_role(role1, role2 ...)` works decently for this, and then when you handle the error a `commands.MissingAnyRole` error is thrown instead of a `commands.MissingRole`. The downside is that with `commands.has_any_role()`, if the user has just one of any of the roles specified it will allow you to call the command. You cannot check if the user has `role1` and `role2` with this. [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)

Answer (score -1):

This will let you give a message to the user if they don't have a role. You can also have multiple roles instead of Admin.

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if "Admin" in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send(":smiley: :wave: Hello, there! :heart: ")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not an admin!")
```